# How to use global settings to make the numeric variables retain to two decimal places by default in R?

Tags: r

Just like the question in the title, how to make all numeric variables in R language retain two decimal places by default without using `round()` to set them one by one?

As I know, the option `options(digits=2)` just mean the number of significant digits to print when printing numeric values.

just like:

```
a <- 3/244
b <- round(3/244)
```

how to make the value of a is 0.01, but not 0.01229508

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to customize some functions, output statistical results, and then write an article. The article requires two decimal places. It is troublesome to use ``round()`` one by one in the function, so I want to know if there is a concise method available.

Comment: But if you round the intermediate values of the calculations to such a low precision, the final result may have a pretty large error

Comment: But what about the options(digits=) ? It mean the number of significant digits to print when printing numeric values. What I want achieve is like options(digits=), the  difference is it output two decimal places when printing numeric values.